# HTML Semantics - <span> element and validity

Tags: html, css

Technically speaking would this block of code be valid (would a test say it's valid): `<body><span>Some text</span></body>` as opposed to `<body><p><span>Some text</span></p></body>` - which I know is valid

Comment: Have you even tried to validate it?

Comment: both are valid visit w3c

Comment: I think I remember that inline elements can't be direct child of `body`. I'm lloking for some documentation about this point.

Comment: It's valid HTML...whether it's sematically correct depends on how you intend on using it. There's really two questions here I think.

Comment: does W3 validity service always point out exact flaws in your code or lack thereof? Will definitely go through the validity process. @ enguerranws that is interesting, I didn't know that, let's have a look at the docs. The question basically is whether it Can be used in place of a paragraph tag (and be regarded as valid code).

Comment: @BugZ Please let me know whether my answer was use full for you (so i can update it if needed) ?

Comment: yes, Andriy Ivaneyko, it was useful, it answered my question and pointed me in the right direction for future validation, thank you.

Comment: @BugZ FYI http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's html would be **valid for both cases**.

Take a look on [HTML w3c Validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) for verifrying whther html valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid HTML5, which is [the only HTML suitable for most practical needs](http://html5doctor.com/html5-check-it-before-you-wreck-it-with-miketm-smith/) today. However, formally it won't validate under outdated HTML 4 Strict and XHTML 1 Strict doctypes which required some block-level wrapper between `body` and text content.

Comment: that is interesting, so technically it can be used, today, and be valid however it is best practice to rather use it to target elements, for eg. `<p><span class="span-target">Some text</span></p>` which my boss just told me haha

Comment: Yes, having a proper semantic grouping element for any part of content, in general, improves the maintainability of the markup and thus still is kind of best practice. But it isn't formally required anymore:)

Comment: @BugZ - HTML5 semantics makes it clear that a [paragraph](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#paragraph) is any run of phrasing content (e.g. a single span and its content). The `<p>` element is just to delimit paragraphs between consecutive runs of phrasing content that would otherwise coalesce into a single paragraph.

Comment: ahh I see thank you @Iiya Strelsyn. That is very good to know, thanks very much Alohci